# cpupower bash completion script

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash completion script for the `cpupower` command but I feel that it sucks. It's too long for such a simple task and have too much case/if-else nesting.

It supports all the subcommands of `cpupower` and their options but not the values. It also support the incompatibilities between some options.

```
## Autocompletion bash for the command 'cpupower'
## This software is released into the public domain

## Known bugs, incomplete stuff:
## #000001. Doesn't complete, or validate at all, the cpu list accepted by -c|--cpu
## #000002. There are no man page for 'cpupower idle-info', so his parameters are not supported
## #000003. Doesn't complete or validate any of the command arguments' values
##        * The governor option in frequency-set command is now supported


# Indicate if an item is present in an array
# Usage: in_array "$ITEM" "${ARRAY[@]}"
in_array()
{
    local ITEM
    for ITEM in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$ITEM" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
    return 1
}

_cpupower()
{
    # Global flags
    local FLAG_DEBUG=1
    local FLAG_CPU=2
    local FLAG_COMPGEN_COMMAND=4
    local FLAGS=0
    # frequency-info command flags
    local FLAG_FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT=1
    local FLAG_FREQINFOSET_HUMAN=2
    local FLAG_FREQINFOSET_PROC=4
    local FLAGS_FREQINFO=0
    # frequency-set command flags
    local FLAG_FREQSET_MIN=1
    local FLAG_FREQSET_MAX=2
    local FLAG_FREQSET_GOV=4
    local FLAG_FREQSET_FREQ=8
    local FLAG_FREQSET_RELATED=16
    local FLAGS_FREQSET=0
    # info & set command flags
    local FLAG_INFOSET_PERFBIAS=1
    local FLAG_INFOSET_SCHEDMC=2
    local FLAG_INFOSET_SCHEDSMT=4
    local FLAGS_INFOSET=0
    # monitor command flags
    local FLAG_MONITOR_LIST=1
    local FLAG_MONITOR_INTERVAL=2
    local FLAG_MONITOR_ONLY=4
    local FLAG_MONITOR_SCHED=8
    local FLAG_MONITOR_VERBOSE=16
    local FLAGS_MONITOR=0
    # States
    local STATE_BASE=0 # Initial
    local STATE_CPU_WAITING=1 # Waiting Cpu list
    local STATE_COMMAND_WAITING=2 # Waiting command argument
    local STATE_COMMAND_VALUE_WAITING=3 # Waiting command argument value
    # Current state
    local STATE=$STATE_BASE
    # Debug parameters
    local -a DEBUG_OPTS=("-d" "--debug")
    # Cpu parameters
    local -a CPU_OPTS=("-c" "--cpu")
    # Help parameters (basic help)
    local -a HELP_OPTS=("-h" "--help")
    # Show version parameters
    local -a VERSION_OPTS=("-v" "--version")
    # Commands parameters
    local -a COMMAND_OPTS=("frequency-info" "frequency-set" "idle-info" "info" "set" "monitor" "help")
    # frequency-info command parameters (output, only one allowed)
    # The -s|--stats parameter it's not an "output" parameters in the docs, but cpupower throws the error "You can't specify more than one --cpu parameter and/or more than one output-specific argument".
    local -a FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT_OPTS=("-e" "--debug" "-a" "--related-cpus" "--affected-cpus" "-g" "--governors" "-p" "--policy" "-d" "--driver" "-l" "--hwlimits" "-f" "--freq" "-y" "--latency" "-w" "--hwfreq" "-s" "--stats")
    # frequency-info individual options
    local -a FREQINFOSET_HUMAN_OPTS=("-m" "--human")
    # this frequency-info option is incompatible with the global -c|--cpu option
    local -a FREQINFOSET_PROC_OPTS=("-o" "--proc")
    # frequency-set command individual parameters
    local -a FREQSET_MIN_OPTS=("-d" "--min")
    local -a FREQSET_MAX_OPTS=("-u" "--max")
    local -a FREQSET_GOV_OPTS=("-g" "--governor")
    local -a FREQSET_FREQ_OPTS=("-f" "--freq")
    local -a FREQSET_RELATED_OPTS=("-r" "--related")
    # frequency-set -g valid values (governors)
    local -a FREQSET_GOV_VALUES=("ondemand" "performance" "conservative" "powersave" "userspace")
    # info command individual parameters
    local -a INFOSET_PERFBIAS_OPTS=("-b" "--perf-bias")
    local -a INFOSET_SCHEDMC_OPTS=("-m" "--sched-mc")
    local -a INFOSET_SCHEDSMT_OPTS=("-s" "--sched-smt")
    # monitor command individual parameters
    local -a MONITOR_LIST_OPTS=("-l")
    local -a MONITOR_INTERVAL_OPTS=("-i")
    local -a MONITOR_ONLY_OPTS=("-m")
    local -a MONITOR_SCHED_OPTS=("-c")
    local -a MONITOR_VERBOSE_OPTS=("-v")
    # Current word
    local CUR_WORD="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    # Last word to process
    local -i LAST_WORD=$COMP_CWORD-1
    # 'compgen' extra arguments
    local COMPGEN_EXTRA=""
    local WORD OPTS CUR_COMMAND CUR_OPT

    for WORD in "${COMP_WORDS[@]:1:$LAST_WORD}"; do
        [ -z "$WORD" ] && continue
        case $STATE in
            $STATE_BASE)
                in_array "$WORD" "${HELP_OPTS[@]}" && return 0
                in_array "$WORD" "${VERSION_OPTS[@]}" && return 0
                if in_array "$WORD" "${DEBUG_OPTS[@]}"; then
                    (( $FLAGS & $FLAG_DEBUG )) && return 1
                    (( FLAGS |= $FLAG_DEBUG ))
                elif in_array "$WORD" "${CPU_OPTS[@]}"; then
                    (( $FLAGS & $FLAG_CPU )) && return 1
                    STATE=$STATE_CPU_WAITING
                elif in_array "$WORD" "${COMMAND_OPTS[@]}"; then
                    CUR_COMMAND="$WORD"
                    STATE=$STATE_COMMAND_WAITING
                fi
                ;;
            $STATE_CPU_WAITING)
                (( FLAGS |= $FLAG_CPU ))
                STATE=$STATE_BASE
                ;;
            $STATE_COMMAND_VALUE_WAITING)
                STATE=$STATE_COMMAND_WAITING
                ;;
            $STATE_COMMAND_WAITING)
                CUR_OPT="$WORD"
                case "$CUR_COMMAND" in
                    help)
                        return 0
                        ;;
                    frequency-info)
                        if in_array "$WORD" "${FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_FREQINFO & $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_FREQINFO |= $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT ))
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${FREQINFOSET_HUMAN_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_FREQINFO & $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_HUMAN )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_FREQINFO |= $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_HUMAN ))
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${FREQINFOSET_PROC_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_FREQINFO & $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_PROC )) && return 1
                            (( $FLAGS_FREQINFO & $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_FREQINFO |= ( $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT | $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_PROC ) ))
                        fi
                        ;;
                    frequency-set)
                        # The -f|--freq option is incompatible with ALL the other parameters
                        (( $FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_FREQ )) && return 1
                        if in_array "$WORD" "${FREQSET_MIN_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_MIN )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_FREQSET |= $FLAG_FREQSET_MIN ))
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${FREQSET_MAX_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_MAX )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_FREQSET |= $FLAG_FREQSET_MAX ))
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${FREQSET_GOV_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_GOV )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_FREQSET |= $FLAG_FREQSET_GOV ))
                            STATE=$STATE_COMMAND_VALUE_WAITING
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${FREQSET_RELATED_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_RELATED )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_FREQSET |= $FLAG_FREQSET_RELATED ))
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${FREQSET_FREQ_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( FLAGS_FREQSET |= $FLAG_FREQSET_FREQ ))
                        fi
                        ;;
                    idle-info)
                        return 0
                        ;;
                    'set'|'info')
                        if in_array "$WORD" "${INFOSET_PERFBIAS_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_INFOSET & $FLAG_INFOSET_PERFBIAS )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_INFOSET |= $FLAG_INFOSET_PERFBIAS ))
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${INFOSET_SCHEDMC_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_INFOSET & $FLAG_INFOSET_SCHEDMC )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_INFOSET |= $FLAG_INFOSET_SCHEDMC ))
                            STATE=$STATE_COMMAND_VALUE_WAITING
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${INFOSET_SCHEDSMT_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_INFOSET & $FLAG_INFOSET_SCHEDSMT )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_INFOSET & $FLAG_INFOSET_SCHEDSMT ))
                            STATE=$STATE_COMMAND_VALUE_WAITING
                        fi
                        ;;
                    monitor)
                        (( $FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_LIST )) && return 1
                        if in_array "$WORD" "${MONITOR_LIST_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( FLAGS_MONITOR |= $FLAG_MONITOR_LIST ))
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${MONITOR_INTERVAL_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_INTERVAL )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_MONITOR |= $FLAG_MONITOR_INTERVAL ))
                            STATE=$STATE_COMMAND_VALUE_WAITING
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${MONITOR_ONLY_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_ONLY )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_MONITOR |= $FLAG_MONITOR_ONLY ))
                            STATE=$STATE_COMMAND_VALUE_WAITING
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${MONITOR_SCHED_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_SCHED )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_MONITOR |= $FLAG_MONITOR_SCHED ))
                        elif in_array "$WORD" "${MONITOR_VERBOSE_OPTS[@]}"; then
                            (( $FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_VERBOSE )) && return 1
                            (( FLAGS_MONITOR |= $FLAG_MONITOR_VERBOSE ))
                        fi
                        ;;
                esac
                ;;
        esac
    done

    OPTS=""
    case $STATE in
        $STATE_BASE)
            OPTS="${COMMAND_OPTS[@]} ${HELP_OPTS[@]} ${VERSION_OPTS[@]}"
            (( ~$FLAGS & $FLAG_DEBUG )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${DEBUG_OPTS[@]}"
            (( ~$FLAGS & $FLAG_CPU )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${CPU_OPTS[@]}"
            ;;
        $STATE_CPU_WAITING)
            ;;
        $STATE_COMMAND_VALUE_WAITING)
            case "$CUR_OPT" in
                "${FREQSET_GOV_OPTS[@]}")
                    OPTS="${FREQSET_GOV_VALUES[@]}"
                ;;
            esac
            ;;
        $STATE_COMMAND_WAITING)
            case "$CUR_COMMAND" in
                help)
                    OPTS="${COMMAND_OPTS[@]}"
                    ;;
                frequency-info)
                    if (( ~$FLAGS_FREQINFO & $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT )); then
                        # The -o|--proc option is incompatible with the -c|--cpu global option
                        if (( ~$FLAGS_FREQINFO & $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_PROC )); then
                            (( ~$FLAGS & $FLAG_CPU )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${FREQINFOSET_PROC_OPTS[@]}"
                        fi
                        OPTS="$OPTS ${FREQINFOSET_OUTPUT_OPTS[@]}"
                    fi
                    (( ~$FLAGS_FREQINFO & $FLAG_FREQINFOSET_HUMAN )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${FREQINFOSET_HUMAN_OPTS[@]}";
                    ;;
                frequency-set)
                    (( $FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_FREQ )) && return 0
                    (( ~$FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_MIN )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${FREQSET_MIN_OPTS[@]}"
                    (( ~$FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_MAX )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${FREQSET_MAX_OPTS[@]}"
                    (( ~$FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_GOV )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${FREQSET_GOV_OPTS[@]}"
                    (( ~$FLAGS_FREQSET & $FLAG_FREQSET_RELATED )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${FREQSET_RELATED_OPTS[@]}"
                    [ $FLAGS_FREQSET -eq 0 ] && OPTS="$OPTS ${FREQSET_FREQ_OPTS[@]}"
                    ;;
                idle-info)
                    return 0
                    ;;
                'set'|'info')
                    (( ~$FLAGS_INFOSET & $FLAG_INFOSET_PERFBIAS )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${INFOSET_PERFBIAS_OPTS[@]}"
                    (( ~$FLAGS_INFOSET & $FLAG_INFOSET_SCHEDMC )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${INFOSET_SCHEDMC_OPTS[@]}"
                    (( ~$FLAGS_INFOSET & $FLAG_INFOSET_SCHEDSMT )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${INFOSET_SCHEDSMT_OPTS[@]}"
                    ;;
                monitor)
                    (( $FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_LIST )) && return 0
                    if (( ~$FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_INTERVAL )); then
                        OPTS="$OPTS ${MONITOR_INVERVAL_OPTS[@]}"
                        # The monitor command accepts a command as an argument.
                        (( FLAGS |= $FLAG_COMPGEN_COMMAND ))
                    fi
                    (( ~$FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_ONLY )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${MONITOR_ONLY_OPTS[@]}"
                    (( ~$FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_SCHED )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${MONITOR_SCHED_OPTS[@]}"
                    (( ~$FLAGS_MONITOR & $FLAG_MONITOR_VERBOSE )) && OPTS="$OPTS ${MONITOR_VERBOSE_OPTS[@]}"
                    [ $FLAGS_MONITOR -eq 0 ] && OPTS="$OPTS ${MONITOR_LIST_OPTS[@]}"
                    ;;

            esac
            ;;
    esac

    (( $FLAGS & $FLAG_COMPGEN_COMMAND )) && COMPGEN_EXTRA="$COMPGEN_EXTRA -c"
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen $COMPGEN_EXTRA -W "${OPTS}" -- ${CUR_WORD}) )
    return 0
}

complete -r cpupower 2>/dev/null
complete -F _cpupower cpupower
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this a bit overkill for a bash completion script?
2. Any ideas on how to refactor it without losing functionality?

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes this starts to look a bit like godzilla, no dealbreaker though.
2. Divide this bulk in several parts. Here some tips to get started:

---

1. Start moving all your variable declarations to a separate file which you will source. This is going to be your *config file*.

   We are talking about the first 80  lines of your `_cpupower()` function here. That is almost 30% of your total amount of lines (!)
2. Move big items you have in your outer `case` construct, to separate functions. Especially the nested case and the big `if`/`elif` parts.
   So you get `case` and `esac` at least on the same page. This will make debugging a lot easier.
3. Big static sequences of commands feel best at home in a function.

   What they do can easily be described in a few words. So these words can be the name of the function. This way the blocks are easy to manouver inside the code.
4. If you grow a lot of (small and clear) functions, put them in a separate file which you can source, and sort them in categories alphabetically. This way you can find them quickly. Consider this file as a "library" so you have a sort of a guideline how to handle it. It also makes it very easy to add or remove extra functionality without hacking away in the *one-big-file*

If you do these things you will see that it will not only look much smaller and easier to handle but also that you can enable and disable entire parts on the fly with a single `#`. Also is this the best starting position if you want to slim down the code effectively. By having a better overview you will spot optimization possibilities sooner and with more ease

---

### tl:dr

1. every `case` - `esac` in its own function (possibly a separate file)
2. every big `if`/`elif` sequence in its own function (possibly a separate file)
3. every simple sequence or stanza of commands in its own function
4. all 80 declarations together in a config file
5. all functions together in a library file

Above tips creates a construction/framework that makes slimming down the code selectively a much easier task. It also makes you more efficient in optimizing a thing or two.

Well, these were the answers to your questions. If these answers brought you some more questions, don't hesitate to ask.